# Buffer.clear() is working but buffer.pop() isn't

Tags: debugging, rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I'm new to Rust and wanted some help because I can't figure out why this simple code is not working.

I'm using rdev library and I'm just trying to store the typed key in a buffer and delete the last letter when I press backspace key.

What is weird is that the backspace key trigger correctly but nothing happen when  `pop()` method is called, thus I'm wondering what's wrong here?

`.clear()` method seems to work correctly.

I'm using **rdev = "0.5.2"**

```
use rdev::{listen, Event, EventType, Key};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Default)]
struct AppState {
    buffer: String,
}

fn handle_key(app_state: &mut AppState, event: &Event) {            
    if let Some(ref string) = event.name  {
            app_state.buffer.push_str(string);
    }
    else if let EventType::KeyRelease(key) = event.event_type {
        if key == Key::Backspace {
            app_state.buffer.pop();
        }
        if key == Key::Escape {
            app_state.buffer.clear()
        }
        println!("buffer : {}", app_state.buffer);
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app_state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(AppState::default()));

    let callback = {
        move |event: Event| {
            let mut app_state = app_state.lock().unwrap();
            handle_key(&mut app_state, &event);
        }
    };

    if let Err(error) = listen(callback) {
        println!("Error: {:?}", error)
    }

}
```

Thank you for you help regarding this.
Also if you think there is a better way to store the pressed keys let me know. Maybe there's a way to store the key and check if the user delete not only the last key but maybe also keys that are in a middle of a word for example.

Comment: For debugging, I would print out the character that is returned by `pop()`. I have a feeling you are getting more characters pushed into your buffer than you expect. This would result in  `pop()` is still popping off characters, but not the characters you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `buffer.pop` is working, but the problem is with the backspace. According to your logic, when you press backspace, a `KeyPress` event with backspace (`Ascii code 08`) arrives and gets inserted to the buffer first. Then when you release the key, your code handles `KeyRelease` separately and that is where you pop that last `08` back.

You can either double pop with backspace, or try to avoid inserting a string when backspace is pressed.

**Double pop:** If you add a second `pop` operation, you will get what you want:

```rust
   ...
   ...
   if key == Key::Backspace {
      let c = app_state.buffer.pop();
      println!("C: {:#?}", c.unwrap());
      let c = app_state.buffer.pop();
      println!("C: {:#?}", c.unwrap());
    }
   ...
   ...
```

Or a better alternative:

**Avoid backspace being inserted to the buffer**:

```rust
   ...
   ...
fn handle_key(app_state: &mut AppState, event: &Event) {
  if let Some(ref string) = event.name  {
    if "\u{0008}" != string {
      app_state.buffer.push_str(string);
    }
  }
  ...
```

A third approach would be to refactor your code to handle `KeyPress` as well and insert the character if its a `printable` character and avoid the rest..